# Is more opium produced legally or illegally?

Tags: data-request, statistics

I've had a hard time finding statistics on legal and illegal opium poppy production.

At the [UNODC](https://www.unodc.org/unodc/en/alternative-development/illicit-crop-cultivation.html) we find facts like:

> global [illicit] opium production fell by almost 30%, to less than 5,000 tons in 2012

while the undated [DEA Museum](https://www.deamuseum.org/ccp/opium/production-distribution.html) claims that:

> Legal growing of opium for medicinal use currently takes place in India, Turkey, and Australia. Two thousand tons of opium are produced annually and this supplies the world with the raw material needed to make medicinal products.

But it is hard to imagine the legal production of opium being capped to two thousand tons for all eternity. An [article at the Transnational Institute](https://www.tni.org/es/node/14852) website, dated 2005, contains some more realistic-sounding information:

> Australia is the largest producer of legally permitted opium, doubling production in the past five years. Opium production in Spain tripled in that time, while legally-sanctioned poppy fields prosper in France, India, Turkey and Hungary. Even Britain is now growing opium poppies legally. The state monopoly in India, meanwhile, produces about the same amount of legal opium - 821 tons in 2002 - as Burma does illegally (828 tons). Worldwide, more opium is produced legally than illegally.

Unfortunately, the sources for this data are not cited. I'm particularly interested in the last claim, "Worldwide, more opium is produced legally than illegally."

Illegal opium production [is supposed to have crashed towards the end of the last decade](https://jied.lse.ac.uk/articles/10.31389/jied.45/). This is apparently because the market for naturally-derived heroin from Afghanistan and Mexico has been replaced by synthetic fentanyl from Chinese factories, which is more compact and easier to transport. In consequence, I would guess that now more opium poppy is being grown for legal production than illegal. However, I'm curious what the case was during earlier decades. I'm also curious what the typical ratio is between legal and illegal production quantities, and how that has varied over time.